# Ошибки. Пунктуация

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

> *Наша учительница истории рассказывала нам, сначала, про древних египтян, населявших северную Африку, потом, на следующей лекции, про древних римлян, потом про средневековье и рыцарские турниры.*

Укажите, пожалуйста, на ошибки в пунктуации.

Comment: @oleedd Иду по вашим стопам с неодолимой настойчивостью. Просьба: *Укажите, пожалуйста, на ошибки в пунктуации*. Спор о средневековье (Средневековье), конечно, безумно интересен, но к пунктуационной истине он никак не приближает. Ответьте по существу, немедленно!

Answer (score 1):

Есть и орфографическая.
Средневековье здесь надо с большой буквы:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: "Если вы выпили волшебного снадобья и попали в средневековье, не надейтесь на свой сотовый телефон и службу спасения". Здесь тоже с прописной? Может, только в специальной и учебной литературе? В  заданном предложении прописная буква тоже выглядит странно (разговорная речь).  "По потрескавшимся дорогам разъезжали всадники, на первых этажах зданий толпились люди, выглядевшие так, словно я попал в средневековье". [Школьники: чего они ждут от XXI века // «Кот Шрёдингера», 2017]

Comment: Идите и спорьте с учёными, которые работают над этим словарём. Вы недалеко от них.

Comment: Вы же всегда рекомендовали ориентироваться по орфографическому словарю.

Comment: Я вообще никогда не спорю, просто хотела узнать ваше мнение. Знаю, что употребление прописных букв в именах собственных часто зависит от СТИЛЯ.  И вот в заданном предложении прописная буква как-то не смотрится, похожа на небоскреб среди сельских домиков. Текст выглядит некрасиво. Нельзя информацию воспринимать  "в лоб", напрямую.   Каждое утверждение верно в определенных пределах, которые в данном случае в словаре не обозначены.

Comment: Мне показалось, что здесь нужна прописная (вообще ничего не знал), потом заглянул в орфографический словарь. Здесь явно: *потом про эпоху...*

Comment: Значение верное, но стиль неподходящий. Средневековье упоминается как средневековое время

Comment: Не думаю, что написание этого слова может зависеть от стиля. Разве что в плане того, что в разговорном стиле часто ошибки :) Но здесь больше не разговорный стиль речи (оформление мыслей), а разговорная тематика.

Comment: Нет, не думаю. Разговорный стиль – это наша обычная речь в диалогах. Если бы все эпохи были обозначены с прописной буквы, тогда выбор был бы понятен.

Comment: Вы знаете, где находится институт Виноградова? Они все там. Может, вы рядом живёте. Просто я больше по пунктуации и стилистике. *Разговорный стиль – это наша обычная речь в диалогах* — да, но есть ещё разговорное оформление (которое бы не подошло для статей и т.п.), а здесь оформление литературное (всё чётко), поэтому поделил бы на тематику и оформление. Понимаю, что стиль определяют по предназначению текста, но не всё так однозначно.

Comment: Стиль определяют по лексике, по более простому синтаксису. Здесь вот что не стыкуется: рассказывала про древних египтян,  про древних римлян,  про средневековье (средневековое время). это и есть разговорный стиль.  Само сочетание "рассказывать  ПРО" не используется в книжной речи.

Comment: Имеете в виду слово "про"? Его уже можно литературным считать, доросло.

Comment: А учителя разве читают лекции? Лекция — это вузовская форма обучения.

Comment: Кстати, книжное характерно только для книг, литературное же подходит везде.

Comment: oleedd, у вас мышление интересное, я даже его определить не могу.  У вас общее представление состоит из многих частных, а цельного образа не создается. Может, это колледж, там лекции читают.  Литературный и книжный – это почти одно и то же.. ПРО, предлог. кого-что. 1. О ком-, чём-л., относительно, насчёт кого-, чего-л. Рассказывать про свой отпуск, про экскурсии, про новых друзей. Про меня забыли. Фильм про любовь.  Все примеры из разговорной речи.

Comment: *Литературный и книжный – это почти одно и то же* — мне так не кажется. Просто учителя вроде бы только в школе.

Comment: Ладно, пока, мне как бы сейчас некогда, ухожу.

Comment: Да, так и в словаре: Лицо, занимающееся преподаванием какого-нибудь предмета в низшей и средней школе, преподаватель, школьный работник.

Answer (score 0):

Не надо обосабливать "сначала".

Comment: А почему «на следующей лекции» обособляется?

Comment: @Фэйсбук конкретизация

Comment: @Фэйсбук: да, поясняется "потом".